# Is it possible to automate Siebel testing behind the GUI?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, testing, qtp, siebel

My test team currently uses QTP to test through the GUI, but like any automated test suite that relies on the interface, it is more fragile than automating tests that directly interact with the code. I am attempting to learn more about Siebel and Siebel Tools to better understand how we might be able to test below the GUI, but would like to hear from someone with more expertise to find out if this is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really depends on what you want to test, I guess.

I'm using the Siebel Java Data Bean (JDB) a lot to access Siebel. You basically connect to the Siebel Server and execute code very similar to eScript. That means you could create records, invoke workflows and so on; basically everything you could do in eScript. That might be helpful. This will apply all the usual validations, runtime events and events.

As soon as some of your scripts in BusComps or in Business Services or elsewhere access data that needs a UI context (`TheApplication().ActiveBusObject()` or `TheApplication().ActiveApplet()` for instance) this approach will fail, though, because the Siebel Data Bean doesn't have a UI context.

Another drawback is that you have to connect to a Siebel Server. That means you have to deploy your SRF to the development server and only then you can run your tests. It sure would be much better if the JDB could connect to your local instance, but as far as I know this is not possible. Have a look at the Object Interfaces guide in the Bookshelf, though. There are different ways to connect to Siebel, not just Java.

Let me know if you have any questions about this. I could maybe post some sample code of how to connect to the Siebel Server etc.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'll check with our developers to see if this is feasible in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

Since Siebel version 7.7 QTP uses [Siebel Test Automation (STA)](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/siebel/crm-technology/041919.htm) **which needs to be purchased separately from Oracle**, a quick search found this explanation on how to [set up testing with STA](http://www.learnqtp.com/points-to-take-care-with-siebel-add-in/) (this is written from a QTP prespective but is true for all STA usage).

If you really want to avoid using GUI testing then you can hunt down the API documentation and try to use STA directly but I would not recommend it, QTP has already done all the heavy lifting for you, why would you want to reproduce the effort (especially since your company already owns QTP licenses).

Answer (score 0):

Right now QTP is the best way to go - it's still a PITA but there really is nothing else out there to test the full Siebel Web Client. This is because the Siebel UI is delivered through Internet Explorer with proprietary Active X and Java controls and so you really need a bespoke pack to test it.

Because the UI is a re-interpretation, not just an abstraction, of the Business Object layer (that one accesses with Data Beans / COM etc.) it is not useful to test at that layer except in a small number of unit test cases (such as when you have complex scripting in Siebel).

If you change the end of the URL for the client (login to Siebel first of course) to something like "SWEcmd=GotoPageTab&SWEScreen=Accounts+Screen&SWESetMarkup=XML" then you'll see lots of  XML mark-up which is then consumed by the proprietary controls - you might think this would be a cool way to build an automation tool, but it is not (I've tried).

If you want to really use a proper UI testing tool, like Selenium, you'll have to test the HTML Siebel Web Client - this is a 'skinny' 'Standard Interactivity' UI that doesn't use Active X or Java ... it has a lot less cool UI controls but it works essentially  the same at the full Siebel Web Client (aka High Interactivity Siebel Web Client, or HI for short), and it works in Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Oracle Application testing Suite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/twp-ats-test-siebel-133042.pdf). It comes pre-built accelerators for testing Siebel which makes it all the more easier to test Siebel.